# Validity of an integral inequality

Tags: analysis, inequality, definite-integrals

Suppose we have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$  And $f(x)<g(x)$ for all values of $n$ 
Then for arbitrary $a$ and $b$ (within the range) is it true that
$$\int_b^{a}\frac{dx}{f(x)} >  \int_b^{a}\frac{dx}{g(x)} $$
If not, then what is true about the relation between $\int_b^{a}\frac{dx}{f(x)}\mbox{ and }\int_b^{a}\frac{dx}{g(x)}$?

Comment: Are $x$ and $n$ the same?

Comment: Don’t you need to know whether $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have the same sign? Else, take $f(x)=-x^3$, $g(x) = x^3$ on $(-\infty, 0)$. Then take $a = -1$, $b = -2$, and the inequality doesn’t hold (the integrals are $\pm 3/8$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are positive in $[a,b]$, than the inequality holds.